# idea. svn commit dialog. What does it mean change list select?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, commit

I use idea as svn client.

After some actions it looks like this:

[image]

Change list dialog became active and by default selected **merge from phase7(1)**.  Phase7 is a branch inside repository.

If to choose `default` at this select - I don't see changes(file dissappears from dialog)

I am confusing what does change list mean? how to return all as was before?

### P.S.

before this dialog looked like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Local Changes tab of the Version Control tool window. You will find all active change lists there. That is also the place where you can move the changes in your *merge from phase7(1)* change list to the *Default* change list, set  *Default* to be the active change list, and remove any change lists you don't need anymore. The *merge from phase7(1)* was probably created automatically when you performed a merge with that branch.

See also the documentation for [Version Control Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-tool-window.html) and [Changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/changelist.html).